# Is synchronized enough to make the drainTo() method of a BlockingQueue atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

If I simply do something like this:

```
synchronized(taskQueue) { //taskQueue is a BlockingQueue 
  taskQueue.drainTo(tasks); //tasks is a list
}
```

Am I assured that concurrent calls to `taskQueue.put()` and `taskQueue.take()` can not be executed inside the synchronized block?

In other words, am I making the drainTo() method atomic?

**Or more generally, how do I make a composition of thread safe operations atomic?**

Example:

```
if(taskQueue.size() == 1) {
   /*Do a lot of things here, but I do not want other threads
     to change the size of the queue here with take or put*/
}
//taskQueue.size() must still be equal to 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below excerpt from [Java docs of BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

> **BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe**. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms
>   of concurrency control. However, the bulk Collection operations
>   addAll, containsAll, retainAll and removeAll are not necessarily
>   performed atomically unless specified otherwise in an implementation.
>   So it is possible, for example, for addAll(c) to fail (throwing an
>   exception) after adding only some of the elements in c.

Also, check the example which shows that a BlockingQueue implementation can safely be used with multiple producers and multiple consumers.

So, if you are not using bulk Collection operations like `addAll, containsAll, retainAll and removeAll`  then you are thread safe.

You even don't need `synchronized(taskQueue) {` and can directly use `taskQueue.drainTo(tasks);` because *BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe* for non-bulk-collection operations like `put`, `take`, `drainTo` etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. In general how would you synchronize the whole queue for a sequence of thread.safe operations (to make the sequence atomic)? For example, if you want to check if the size of the queue is 0 and do something on the queue without any other concurrent operations on it (like take and put). Is synchronized enough?

Comment: You will need explicit synchronization using synchronized methods and statement (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) only if you are not using a Java's thread-safe API. In your case, since you are using `BlockingQueue` and its implementations are thread safe for non-bulk-collection operations, so you need not to do an explicit synchronization. Check the examples in the link I provided, there `put` and `take` methods are used without any explicit synchronization.

Comment: There are multiple implementations of `BlockingQueue` like `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`, read docs for which one suits your requirement best.

Comment: I added another example at the end of my question. It is true that the collection is thread safe, but a composition of thread safe operations can not be atomic. Inside the if, what prevents other threads from calling take or put? Thanks!

Comment: `taskQueue.size()` is inherited from `java.util.Collection` so it is not thread-safe and will not  provide synchronization. It is only the `BlockingQueue ` methods which are thread safe. If you want to achieve what you mentioned in your edited question, then you need to synchronize those statements using `taskQueue` object so that no other thread can take lock of your `taskQueue` object for `put` or `take`. But you should read about **"Reentrant Synchronization"** from Java docs, which means same thread can do `put` or `take` because it can re-acquire the lock of object it is already holding.

Comment: @jameslarge I agree that an there is no explicit contracts between Interface and implementation classes apart from normal inheritance contracts which we are aware of, but in case of `BlockingQueue` it is explicitly mention in Java docs that - "BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe." and "bulk Collection operations addAll, containsAll, retainAll and removeAll are not necessarily performed atomically unless specified otherwise in an implementation" So, I don't feel the need to check the API code and verify. OP is concerned about non-bulk collection operations.

Comment: @jameslarge Java doc reference which you have quoted "The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress." tell about the thread safety of the collection object which the queue is processing and not the queue itself. They are still thread-safe. OP is concerned about the atomic behavior of queue API queue - "In other words, am I making the drainTo() method atomic?"

Comment: @jameslarge Not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Take a LinkedBlockingQueue as an example, it has a 'takeLock' and 'putLock' which are its member variables.

So client side synchronization dose not help here, since other 'take' actions are not guarded by this lock, even if this lock comes from the queue itself.

The drainTo() method is guarded by 'takeLock', for any other 'take' operation it's thread safe. But for the 'put' operations, they are guarded by 'putLock', so will not be affected.

So I think nothing is needed here!

Comment: Not sure I understood. I do not want any put to be performed while I am executing the drainTo() method.

Comment: @Kami, if you use LinkedBlockingQueue, then just use drainTo() without synchronization is enough. You can read the source code if still not clear.

Comment: I added another example at the end of my question. It is true that the collection is thread safe, but a composition of thread safe operations can not be atomic. Inside the if, what prevents other threads from calling take or put? Thanks!